# Como criar uma nova database no ORACLE?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle, oracle11g, sqldeveloper

Instalei o oracle database, oracle client e sql developer num windows 8.1 64 bits.

Com a instalação do oracle database foi criada uma database em localhost:1521

Mas agora gostaria de criar uma nova database nessa conexão.

Como posso fazer isso? É possível através do sql developer?

Comment: Database não tem porta. O servidor de banco de dados responde na porta 1521.

Comment: Verdade, acho que confundi os conceitos. Vou alterar a pergunta

Comment: conecta no usuário sys com a senha que você definiu ao instalar o client, e depois cria a database e os usuários. Para pegar o TNS, você precisa procurar dentro da instalação o arquivo "TNSNAMES.ORA"